# codeigniter Fatal error while calling a function menu from application/core/MY_Controller.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error for a small module that I am trying to develop:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method `car_booking::getMenu()` in
>   /var/www/html/mis_mishra/application/core/MY_Controller.php on line 67

The same is working fine for other module. I have checked from my side that the case is ok, module is available menu is coming perfectly alright when the module start. unable to trace the reason.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Edit your question with your MY_Controller

Comment: Make sure file name start with capital C like `Car_booking.php`